# Android ListView ClickEvent not working

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I am using Custom `ListView` in Android and everything is working fine fetching data into list. Earlier the click event working fine with it but when I applied custom `TextView` and `LinerLayout` with a custom background in litst_view_item.xml file its click event not working right now please help me.
How can I remove this error ?

I tried all code samples like :

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

in every layout item in list_view_item.xml (even in linearlayout)

and

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

in listview_activity.xml file

in listview attribute and in its parent LinearLayout.xml

Please if someone know about this problem, please help me

Answer (score 0):

Apply this to  ParentLayout in `list_view_item.xml`  not inside ListView Attribute or anywhere in your ListView Activity and no need of using `focusinTouchmode` if you use `blocksDescendants` in parentAttribute.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Comment: I removed  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" from listview_acitivity.xml and added to rootview listview_item.xml in uppermost layout which is LinearLayout but still not getting any respose ..... Please do a help if any other suggestion

Comment: remove it every where in your ListView Activity,it should be only in your `listview_view.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Remove android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" from listview_activity.xml and add it in top-level layout of list_view_item.xml.

Comment: If possible , Can u post list_view_item.xml ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sahityakumarsuman/e9f129a878395568881f     . this is the github where i had put the code of list_item_code

Comment: this is list_item.xml code =  gist.github.com/sahityakumarsuman/e9f129a878395568881f    and this is list_view_activity.xml code = https://gist.github.com/sahityakumarsuman/e639f3e34ce47620059c    , and Adapter code is = https://gist.github.com/sahityakumarsuman/4e4cbd190a5076be3909  and activity class is = https://gist.github.com/sahityakumarsuman/f5a717addfdda131ff91

Comment: I did not get why are you using scrollview in list item layout. Also android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false" should be added to view which need to be clickable in list item(eg: button in the list item). You have added to the attribute for all the views.

Comment: So as according to you what should I, and used scrollview because I have used a lot of view in the xml and file and i am getting the text from these views in next activity, but should not be visible all to those people that's why I did so, Can i use this attribute in linearlayout too

Answer (score 0):

try using custom listView Adapter, and add onClick listener to the view layout like this:

```
public listviewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> list) {

            this.activity = activity;
            this.list = list;

        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        private class ViewHolder {
            LinearLayout linearLayout;
            TextView txtview; 


        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;
            LayoutInflater inflater =  activity.getLayoutInflater();

            if (convertView == null){

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtview);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            holder.txtview.setText(list.get(position));
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //do something 
                }
            });
}}
```

and in the onCreate you need to set the adapter to the list:

```
listviewAdapter adapter = new listviewAdapter(ActivityName.this, list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

this way you wont need to set an OnItemSelectedListener for the list.

Comment: sorry but there is not button in liste_item.xml file , There is only text view ...in it .........but yes when next activity will open then it it has button in it but it is totaly different in context